# Importing CSV files keeping UTF-8 format

Tags: excel, vba, csv, utf-8

I am importing a batch of csv files from a folder all in separate worksheets, yet when I import the file, my new data loses leading zeroes for numbers and also loses its UTF-8 format. Is there any possible way to import the csv files while keeping leading zeroes and UTF-8 format?

Below is my vba

```
Option Explicit
Sub ImportCSVs()

Dim fPath   As String
Dim fCSV    As String
Dim wbCSV   As Workbook
Dim wbMST   As Workbook

Set wbMST = ThisWorkbook
fPath = "C:\mycsvfiles\Q3 2017\"                  'path to CSV files, include the final \
Application.ScreenUpdating = False  'speed up macro
Application.DisplayAlerts = False   'no error messages, take default answers
fCSV = Dir(fPath & "*.csv")         'start the CSV file listing

On Error Resume Next
Do While Len(fCSV) > 0
    Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fCSV)                    'open a CSV file
    wbMST.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Delete                       'delete sheet if it exists
    ActiveSheet.Move After:=wbMST.Sheets(wbMST.Sheets.Count)    'move new sheet into Mstr
    Columns.AutoFit             'clean up display
    fCSV = Dir                  'ready next CSV
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set wbCSV = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thanks a million in advance! Let me know if I can provide additional information

Comment: Import using Data, External Data, From Text. Select UTF-8 as the origin and set hte columns of numbers with leading zeroes to Text.

Comment: Jeeped, thanks for the feedback. The problem with this is that it would take too long as I have over 100 files. Is there a code I could add to my vba that would do those steps automatically?

Comment: Don't `Workbooks.Open` the CSV files. CSV files are just plain text files that you can open through a `FileSystemObject` (reference the *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* library) and use streams to load the data (preserving the encoding) into an array - cycle through all the files and then dump the array into the target sheet in one single operation.

Comment: Have a look at the Workbooks.OpenText method, which will allow you set the origin of the text file and format your column as Text.

Comment: Losing leading zeroes is a side-effect of Excel representing numbers as numbers. If you need them as strings, prepend a single quote or format the destination column as text. But using `Workbooks.Open[Whatever]` is going to be painfully slow if you have to process a hundred files. Do the work in memory, yourself; interact with Excel worksheets as little as possible, and you'll have decent performance.